# Match a specific keyword to a specific result

Tags: algolia

We have a need to make a specific search keyword offer a specific result. Is there a way to do this from within the Algolia console?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such feature out-of-the box but what you can reproduce such behavior using 2 different solutions:

#### Quick work-around: adding the search keywords in your records

You could add a new `keyword` attribute to your objects and list there all the keywords you want to use for every single object.

**with attributesToIndex:**

Putting that `keyword` attribute on top of your `attributesToIndex` will make it match before the other attributes.

**or with attributesForFaceting:**

Putting that `keyword` attribute in the `attributesForFaceting` will let you filter on it. For every single search, you could do an extra query putting the query string as the filter: `index.search('' /* empty query string: match all */, { facetFilters: "keyword:THE_USER_QUERY_STRING" })` and check use the results if there is a match, otherwise use the regular search query.

#### Better option: using an additional index

Using an additional index, you would push 1 record per search keyword you want to handle.

A record of such index would look like this:

```
{
   "keyword": "mykeyword",
   "object": {
     // the object you want to retrieve
   }
}
```

Configure your `attributesToIndex` with `keyword` only. You may also want to configure the `queryType` of that extra index to `prefixNone` so the native prefix search doesn't trigger. (instead, you could also use the `facetFilters` approach here).

For every single search, you would then query 2 indices: your original index and this extra index. In case the extra one has a match, you can inject the object in your search results.